# Using paperclip in a nested form : reject if incorrect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, nested-attributes

UPDATE

If i remove the reject_if from this line :

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_blogs, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['image_blog'].nil? }
```

It works, how can it be modified to work as intended and prevent an image creation when nil?

---

I am using the following tutorial to create Post with images :
http://sleekd.com/general/adding-multiple-images-to-a-rails-model-with-paperclip/
The goal is to have a post element containing 0-n images blog. images blog is a model containing a paperclip. I am trying to have image_blog elements created at the same time than the post. To do so I use nested forms.

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @post = Post.new
    3.times{ @post.image_blogs.build}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @post }
    end
  end
end
```

-

```
class ImageBlog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessible  :image
  has_attached_file :image , :styles => { :small => "150x150>", :large => "320x240>" }
end
```

-

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :image_blogs, :dependent => :destroy
  validates :title, :content, :presence => true
  validates :title, :uniqueness => true
  acts_as_taggable
  has_attached_file :image
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_blogs, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['image_blog'].nil? }
end
```

-

```
    <%= form_for(@post,:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :title %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :content %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :content, :class => "mceEditor" %>
      </div>
      <%= f.fields_for :image_blogs, do |ib|%>
      <p>
        <%= ib.label "Image du post"%>
        <%= ib.file_field :image %>
        <%#= ib.check_box :_destroy%>
        <%#= ib.label :_destroy,"Effacer l'image" %>
      </p>
      <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I checked that everything was correct using different tutorials about nested paperclip, but it still does not work. The post is created but the images are not copied and no imageblog elements are created.

Why is there no error? why is it not working?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to make a slight correction on the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, inside the lambda, the object you are evaluating is image (attribute of ImageBlog) instead of image_blog, this way:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :image_blogs, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['image'].nil? }
```